# XML Digitial Security - Hmac_SHA1

Tags: digital-signature, digest

I need to create a digest value for the below input

```
<u:Timestamp u:Id="_0" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <u:Created>2015-07-28T13:35:54Z</u:Created>
    <u:Expires>2015-07-28T13:40:49Z</u:Expires>
</u:Timestamp>
```

so am passing the above value as a doc obj to the below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // Create a DOM XMLSignatureFactory that will be used to generate the
    // enveloped signature
    XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
    SecretKey signingKey = new SecretKeySpec("welcome1".getBytes(), "HMAC");
    // Create a Reference to the enveloped document (in this case we are
    // signing the whole document, so a URI of "" signifies that) and
    // also specify the SHA1 digest algorithm and the ENVELOPED Transform.

    Reference ref = fac.newReference
        ("#_0", fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
         Collections.singletonList
          (fac.newTransform
            ("http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#", (TransformParameterSpec) null)),
         null, null);

    // Create the SignedInfo
    SignedInfo si = fac.newSignedInfo
        (fac.newCanonicalizationMethod
         (CanonicalizationMethod.EXCLUSIVE,
          (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
         fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1, null),
         Collections.singletonList(ref));


    // Instantiate the document to be signed
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc =
        dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Signed_Encryp/timestamp.txt"));

    // Create a DOMSignContext and specify the DSA PrivateKey and
    // location of the resulting XMLSignature's parent element
    DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext
        (signingKey, doc.getDocumentElement());

    // Create the XMLSignature (but don't sign it yet)
    XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, null);

    // Marshal, generate (and sign) the enveloped signature
    signature.sign(dsc);

    // output the resulting document
    OutputStream os;
    if (args.length > 1) {
       os = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
    } else {
       os = System.out;
    }

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
    trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
}
```

which returning me a result as

```
<u:Timestamp xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" u:Id="_0">
    <u:Created>2015-07-28T13:35:54Z</u:Created>
    <u:Expires>2015-07-28T13:40:49Z</u:Expires>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1"/>
            <ds:Reference URI="#_0">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                <ds:DigestValue>1X/3X+yCdJc0x3n8guQnlCFvX+s=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>R4ZrHvlvyGvvQYpojZWPgUgRRSw=</ds:SignatureValue>
    </ds:Signature>
</u:Timestamp>
```

here am not confident that digest value is created using the input am passed, also signature is created inside the timestamp tag , is there any option available to create signature tag after the timestamp tag.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

To check if the signature is over the data, simply change the data and use the same key. If the HMAC value changes then the hash clearly is over the data. When changing back it should return to the old value. Note that this is true for HMAC-SHA1, it may *not* be the case for all primitives (e.g. RSA-PSS).

Alternatively, if you're up to it, you can perform the canonicalization yourself and manually calculate the signature. Or try another implementation.

---

If `u:Timestamp` is the root element then you cannot put anything next to it, as XML only has a single root element. You have yourself indicated that the signature is placed at `doc.getDocumentElement()`. You can however create a *detached* signature. Now you know how it is called, you should be able to search for it.

Comment: Anything missing from my answer?